# Compilation error using boost mpl list with BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE

Tags: c++, boost

I have been battling the compiler for sometime now. Here is my code:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>

namespace MyMessageNamespace
{
    class ParticularMessage
    {
        template <int N>
        void SetSomething(int myValue) {};
    };
}

template <typename MyMessageT>
struct MyMessage
{
    using MyMessageType = MyMessageT;
};

using MyMessages = boost::mpl::list<MyMessage<MyMessageNamespace::ParticularMessage>>;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(MyTestCase, MyMessage, MyMessages)
{
    typename MyMessage::MyMessageType message;
    message.SetSomething<1>(20);
}
```

Here is the error I get:

error: reference to non-static member function must be called: message.SetSomething<1>(20);

Comment: Can you make the example complete please? With all the appropriate #include lines. Then I have a chance of fixing it for you.

Comment: `SetSomething` does not have a proper type signature - is it the same in the original code? Also, I assume it's public, right?

Comment: Ill add the header files. And put void infront of SetSomething, and yes it is a public function

Comment: I think that is everything. I am recompiling what is here

Comment: I'm not sure how the scopes go here, can you try `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(MyTestCase, MyMsg, MyMessages) {MyMsg::MyMessageType m; m.SetSomething<1>(20);}` ? because your templated `typedef` has same name as the original template.

Comment: I'm trying that out now

Comment: Nope. It still fails with the same compile error

Comment: The code above should run and give the same error i'm seeing

Comment: I assume you're using Clang, as MSC compiles it well and GCC complains about lack of `operator< `